# Access a React component method / state from outside the component

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs

I have embedded a `reactjs` component into an existing HTML page by referencing it's ID like described in React's tutorial:

```
ReactDOM.render(
  <Page />,
  document.getElementById('my-react-compnent')
);
```

Then:

```
<div id="my-react-compnent></div>
```

The component is displayed and works as expected.

Now I want to link a button located on that page to my component (to be specific I would like to retrive its state, but for the example even invoking one of its methods would be fine).

In other words - when clicking the outside button, I want to invoke a method from the `Page` component?

How can I do that?

Comment: So when you click the outside button, you want to invoke a method from the  `<Page />` component?

Comment: @BrettDeWoody Exactly.

Comment: I would update the question to be more specific about that. It's a bit confusing as is.

Comment: @BrettDeWoody Done. Thank you.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

## The Old Recommendation

Assigning the returned value from `ReactDOM.render` does allow access to the component and it's methods. For example, in a simple app, we might have:

```
const PageComponent = ReactDOM.render(<Page />, document.getElementById("app"));
```

which we can then access using `PageComponent`, and any of its methods can be accessed with `PageComponent.METHOD`.

***However***, according to the docs this might be changed or deprecated and is not recommended.

### The New Recommendation

The new recommendation is to attach a callback `ref` to the root element. Using the same example above:

```
const PageComponent = ReactDOM.render(<Page ref={(pageComponent) => {window.pageComponent = pageComponent}}/>, document.getElementById("app"));
```

which we can then access using `window.pageComponent`, and any of its methods can be accessed with `window.pageComponent.METHOD`.

This also works for child components.

Here's a full example:

```js
class ChildComponent extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      counter: 0
    }
  }

  returnCounter = () => {
    return this.state.counter;
  }
  
  increment = (event) => {
    event.stopPropagation();
    this.setState(prevState => {
      return {
        counter: prevState.counter + 1
      }
    })
  }
  
  render() {
    return (
      <div onClick={this.increment}>
        Child Value - {this.state.counter} - Click to increment
      </div>
    )
  }
}

class Page extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      counter: 0
    }
  }

  returnCounter = () => {
    return this.state.counter;
  }
  
  increment = () => {
    this.setState(prevState => {
      return {
        counter: prevState.counter + 1
      }
    })
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <div onClick={this.increment}>
        <div>Parent Value - {this.state.counter} - Click to increment</div>
        <ChildComponent ref={(childComponent) => {window.childComponent = childComponent}}/>
      </div>
    )
  }
}

ReactDOM.render(<Page ref={(pageComponent) => {window.pageComponent = pageComponent}} />, document.getElementById("app"));

const parentBtn = document.getElementById("parentButton");
parentBtn.addEventListener("click", event => {
  alert(window.pageComponent.returnCounter());
});

const childBtn = document.getElementById("childButton");
childBtn.addEventListener("click", event => {
  alert(window.childComponent.returnCounter());
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.1.0/react.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.1.0/react-dom.min.js"></script>

<div id="app"></div>

<button id="parentButton">Get Parent State</button>
<button id="childButton">Get Child State</button>
```

Comment: Thank you. For some reason `PageComponent` is null for me (the return value of `ReactDOM.render`. I am using `material-ui` and had to wrap my component with `MuiThemeProvider` (see this http://www.material-ui.com/#/customization/themes). Maybe it has something to do with that?

Comment: Yep, the `MuiThemeProvider` wrapper caused this behvior. I made a "clean" component and it works just like yours. :(

Comment: Interesting. I'm trying to access methods of a child component now, which might solve your problem.

Comment: Unfortunately the method of assigning the return of `ReactDOM.render` might be deprecated at some point - https://reactjs.org/docs/react-dom.html#render

Comment: Portals might be another option - https://reactjs.org/docs/portals.html

Comment: @AndyThomas Updated solution to use `refs`, which appear to more future proof, and allows us to access child components, which should solve the issue you encountered.

Comment: Excellent! Thank you so much.

Comment: @BrettDeWoody But `window.pageComponent` does pollute the `window` namespace... any tips on that?