# inner HTML: How to call Method in React Class

Tags: javascript, reactjs, class, mapbox-gl-js

Assume I have an ordinary React Component in which I call [setHMTL](https://docs.mapbox.com/mapbox-gl-js/api/#popup#sethtml).

```
class Foo extends React.Component {

...
.setHTML(
          '<span><p>Foo' + ... 
          + '</p><img onclick="() => this.setState({...})" class="whatever" src.../></span>'
        )
...
```

On the `<img />` Element, I need an `onClick()`. When that function is called, I need to set the`state` of my component.  Normally I would do it in `JSX` like so

```
<img
  src=...
  onClick={() => this.setState({...}) />
```

But how to do it in the case where the `HTML` is a string?

Comment: https://reactjs.org/docs/dom-elements.html#dangerouslysetinnerhtml Is that what you are looking for? Unclear on your question

Comment: So `innerHTML` that you are setting is just a string that you are consuming from whatever it is, so I see couple things that you may be able to use, 1) either do a string match on img tag and then add onClick handler string to it, OR 2) probably do a `ref` on the component that your newly created HTML is going to be attached to and then probably get the HTML within it and then add a listener for your desired selector

Comment: For #2 here's the resource that can help you: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48769763/access-a-react-component-method-state-from-outside-the-component